# Displaying Posts from a specific category in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I can see countless posts regarding this question all over the web, but no matter how many study, I can't seem to get this to work. Could someone help me understand why the code I have isn't working correctly?

To break it down, I have created a custom page template and replicated the code from `page.php` (Default Template). I have then included my args and my post loop, as shown below;

```
<main class="site-main" id="main">

  <?php
    // The Arguments
    $args = array(
      'category_name'  => 'commercial',
      'post_type'      => 'post',
      'post_status'    => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 6
    );  

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    // If posts...
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <!-- Start the loop -->
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'works' ); ?>  
  <?php endwhile; endif; // end the loop. ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</main>
```

> The category I'm trying to target is 'commercial'.

From the front end I get a fully functioning page, no visual errors and everything is displayed correctly. Plainly put it's simply blank. As if the page isn't loading the posts.

> **My question**
>   Is there anything wrong with my code structure? 
>   Or any noticeable syntax errors to experienced WP devs?

Note: Unfortunately, most of the examples I've found on the web are fairly old. I worry that the structure of these examples are out of date. So I have tried to build my loop via the code provided from the docs.

I also tried the route outlined in [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters);

`$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'commercial' ) );`

No luck sadly. :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Regards, -B.

**EDIT: Sun 7th Oct 2018 17:11 (Answered)**

Thanks to @msg's suggestion I can see I was loading the incorrect file path for my loop template. I was so obsessed with the loop, I forgot about it.

**EDIT: Sun 7th Oct 2018 17:11**

After running the following I can see the posts have been collected.

```
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($the_query);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: How did you name your template ? `get_template_part` is trying to load `content-works.php`. Try to dump `$the_query` to check if you are getting any result.

Comment: @msg, I named the file, com-services-page.php. I've ran the dump I can see my posts in the array.

Comment: @msg, I can see the problem after you highlighted, `get_template_part is trying to load content-works.php.` Thanks for the assist. If you want to write out an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query seems ok. If you are getting results the problem most likely is in the template.

The [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) call is trying to load `content-works.php` and as a quirk of this function, is failing silently if it can't find it.